# How to display Crystal report in data table?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, datasource

I am working on window form application and add Crystal Report in the project named "crystalreport1" and in the form1(window form) take CrystalReportViewer1.I want to fill a crystal report via programmatically.

By the following way, I gave data-table to crystal report and then error raised that **REPORT HAS NO TABLES**. How I can solve this problem?

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("id")
dt.Columns.Add("name")
dt.Columns.Add("address")
dt.Rows.Add(1, "ali", "lhr")
dt.Rows.Add(2, "nomi", "mul")
Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
CrystalReportViewer1.Show()
```

Comment: You must pass data to your report, not only set datasource.. pass your data via XML (ADO .NET)

Comment: You must set the database structure in your CrystalReport1 document. It must have the same structure as the DataTable that you are passing to the rpt variable which is an instance of CrystalReport1

Comment: @muhammad, are you design crystal report? the error shows that you must bind datatable with design. You must go step by step. See link - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/create-crystal-report-step-by-step-using-sql-database-view/